# just flip effect actual flip should not happend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that has a background image.  When I click on the div, I  want it to flip and then change the URL of the image to show a different image.  The problem that is happening is the "flipped" image is showing as a mirror image. How can I avoid this?

**CSS**

```css
.imgnew
{
 -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transition:all 1.0s linear;
 transform-style:preserve-3d;
 transition:all 1.0s linear

}

.transition
{
 -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 transform:rotateY(180deg);

}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$('div').add('')
```

**Note:**

I have a div element and no other element can be added to the div or wrapped around it.

I am adding these two classes for the flip.

Comment: Please also share your HTML code

Comment: Please improve the question with more detail.  Parts of the question like " but due to flip image is also flip " don't make sense to me.  I was looking to improve the title but its too hard to know just what the question is

Comment: @mishik  they are just simple div inside html body tag

Comment: @MichaelDurrant tried updating question plz check , when div is flip background image is flip like mirror image . i dont want to flip backround effect .. i am fliping div for 3D transform

Comment: If you could setup a jsfiddle that would be very helpful

Comment: Without a jsFiddle I can't really tell what the issue is, but I have a feeling that it may have to do with not having a `backface-visibility: hidden` set. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$(".imgnew").on('click', function() {  
   $(".imgnew").addClass("transition");   
    setTimeout(function(){  
       $(".imgnew").removeClass("transition");  
    }, 500);  
});
```

That will add the class, and then halfway through the transition, remove it. The effect should not be noticeable, it will just look like a flip, but the resulting div will still be unmirrored.

Here is a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cXDxm/3/) showing this effect